# Помогите запустить строку из Jupiter в PyCharm

Tags: python, pyqt

Всем привет.
Новичок, учусь только.
Прохожу курс на **Youtube** по `ObjetDetection`.

Там в коде есть строка(запуск на `Jupiter`)

```
!cd {LABELIMG_PATH} && pyrcc5 -o libs/resources.py resources.qrc
```

Вроде все просто и понятно.
Но на `PyCharm` не работает..не могу никак адаптировать, застрял.

```
from PyQt5 import pyrcc
pyrcc LABELIMG_PATH//resources.qrc -o LABELIMG_PATH//resources.py
```

```
pyrcc LABELIMG_PATH//resources.qrc -o LABELIMG_PATH//resources.py
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

если так, то

```
from PyQt5 import pyrcc
pyrcc ('LABELIMG_PATH//resources.qr') -o ('LABELIMG_PATH//resources.py')
```

```
    pyrcc ('LABELIMG_PATH//resources.qr') -o ('LABELIMG_PATH//resources.py')
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Что то элементарное ведь упускаю, да?

Comment: Почему вы решили, что конвертацию ресурсного модуля надо делать в PyCharm? Просто в консоли/терминале/CMD выполните:  
`pyrcc5 resources.qrc -o resources_rc.py` и все.

Comment: Спасибо большое, за помощь! Все получилось!